# Apps Script - Clear contents of range but don't clear any filtered results

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet and one of the columns is dates.
I wish to clear all cells in the date column if they are not today's date

```
  filter = range.createFilter();                                                                                               //creates the new filterable range
      filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateBefore(SpreadsheetApp.RelativeDate.TODAY).build();              // filters out today
      addFilter = filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(column,filterCriteria);                                                           // applies the filter
      range = helpersheet.getRange(2,column, helpersheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);                                                     // set range to the filtered date column
      range.setBackground("red");
      range.clear({skipFilteredRows: true});
```

This is as far as I have got, the script successfully filters the column and correctly sets the background to red (I inserted this line for debugging only)

The problem seems to be on the range.clear line.

Using range.clear(); also clears the filtered results
but range.clear({skipFilteredRows: true});  doesn't clear anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification? In this modification, a property of `contentsOnly` is added.

#### From:

```
range.clear({skipFilteredRows: true});
```

#### To:

```
range.clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
```

- By this modification, only the cell values of showing cells are cleared. So, when you remove the basic filter, you can see that the filtered values are not cleared.
- If you want to also clear the background color, please modify it to `range.clear({ contentsOnly: true, formatOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });`.
- If you want to clear only the cells hidden by the basic filter, how about the following modified script?

  ```js
  filter = range.createFilter();
  filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateBefore(SpreadsheetApp.RelativeDate.TODAY).build();
  addFilter = filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(column, filterCriteria);
  range = helpersheet.getRange(2, column, helpersheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);
  range.setBackground("red");

  // I modified the below script.
  const start = 2;
  const end = range.getNumRows() + start;
  const ranges = [];
  for (let r = start; r <= end; r++) {
    if (helpersheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(r)) {
      ranges.push(`B${r}`);
    }
  }
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
    helpersheet.getRangeList(ranges).clearContent();
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [clear(options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear(Object))

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly, I'm surprised that "skipFilteredRows: true" alone doesn't achieve this but really glad I now have the solution

Comment: @Dave Skirrow Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.